# Easiest way to get a GWT project (with RPC) online?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a GWT program with RPCs that works great in Development Mode. It reads/writes from a .txt file in the war folder. I'd like to get it online so, for example, somebody else could visit it on their iPhone using a URL.  I own a GoDaddy hosting account.
I've never used Tomcat before.  I'm looking for the fastest and easiest way to get my project online.  Please help if you can!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that GoDaddy doesn't have any Java hosting packages. That means that you'll need to find another host somewhere else who can run java on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have a Server with a running tomcat/jetty instance and you dont want to host it by yourself, then you should take a look into [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/).

You can find [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/appengine) a very good tutorial, how to publish a GWT-Application to the Google App Engine.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into it. Can you read and write to txt files on the server using the App Engine?

Comment: You cant write to the filesystem in this sandbox. To work with files you have to upload them or you have to use the App Engine datastore or memcache,... If this solution is not good enough for you, you have to use a webcontainer like tomcat or Jetty.

Comment: Ok thanks. And how difficult would it be to get the project from Tomcat to some way that's accessible by URL?

Comment: I dont understand? If you install a tomcat, then you can connect in to it in the standard configuration over localhost:8080 or ip:8080. Here you can find a good tutorial how to install and use a standalone tomcat: http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheTomcat/article.html